# How can I use an object's value, not the literal object name?

Tags: r, object

I'm trying to edit a script to use a variable to change some of the options in an analysis.

In this example, I'm trying to use an object so that I can change which column I'm calling. The columns contain categorical plant traits, and if a plant has two traits, I split its value between both of those traits.

Example data (note that NumTraits gets derived earlier based on which Trait column I want to use, in this example it is Trait1):

| Plant Number | Value | Trait1 | Trait2 | NumTraits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | A | A | 1 |
| 2 | 20 | B | A+B | 1 |
| 3 | 15 | A+B | A+B | 2 |
| 4 | 10 | B | B | 1 |

Existing code:

```
split.data <- data %>%
mutate(NewValue = Value/NumTraits) %>%
tidyr::separate_rows(Trait1, sep = "[+]") %>%
group_by(Trait1) %>%
summarise(NewValue = sum(Value), .groups = 'drop')
```

This produces the desired output:

| PlantNumber | Value | Trait1 | Trait2 | NumTraits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | A | A | 1 |
| 2 | 20 | B | A+B | 1 |
| 3 | 7.5 | A | A+B | 2 |
| 4 | 10 | B | B | 1 |
| 3 | 7.5 | B | A+B | 2 |

(Note that normally the two PlantNumber = 3 rows would be adjacent, but StackOverflow didn't accept that formatting.)

I would like to an object, say `trait.to.use <- "Trait1"`, that I can put in place of Trait1 above to switch between Trait1 and Trait2 throughout my code.

If I replace Trait1 with trait.to.use in the above code, it gives me an error because "trait.to.use" is not a column in my data.
I tried trait.to.use[1] and all_of(trait.to.use), but while they return "Trait1" the code doesn't split the values and the resulting Value column is just "Trait1" every line.

How can I pass the column name in an object to produce the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `!!sym` to make it symbol

```
trait.to.use <- c("Trait1" , "Trait2") 

data %>%
    mutate(NewValue = Value/NumTraits) %>%
    tidyr::separate_rows(!!sym(trait.to.use[1]), sep = "[+]") %>%
    group_by(!!sym(trait.to.use[1])) %>%
    summarise(NewValue = sum(Value), .groups = 'drop')
```

- output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Trait1 NewValue
  <chr>     <int>
1 A            25
2 B            45
```

and then you can just change `trait.to.use[1]` to `trait.to.use[2]`